# Compare a cell reference containing a valid date and the second cell returns invalid if date in second cell is more than 180 days later

Tags: excel, google-sheets, excel-formula

So I have two cells in Google Sheets. One of them is a date for registration and another is date for closure.

First stage is :1) I input a date in the registration date cell
2) Add a function in the closure date cell that returns error or invalid if date of closure is more than 180 days after date of registration.

Since it's comparing a string to number, I'm held up. Any help would be appreciated

Read google sheets function documentation, saw videos on youtube, random google searches pertaining to doubt

code not applicable

Expected result will be an error that will be displayed if date of closure input is more than 180 days than date of registration input

Comment: You tagged excel and excel formula but state you are using google sheets... Which do you want a solution for?

Comment: Google sheets preferably. I thought the formula is still common hence tagged Excel

Comment: So you should tag for googlesheets not excel...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sounds pretty much like data validation.
Example:

[image]

`Sheet1!B2` has set data validation:

`Custom formula is` `=INT(B2)<=(INT(B1)+180)`

Validation text is:

Date of closure must not be more than 180 days after date of registration.

Link to example: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Aqo2zLCevIFii7lQVRQNYUvxrUzXbKvX7w8UGDYxwTw/edit?usp=sharing

As you see your assumption "it's comparing a string to number" is wrong. A date/time is a number in `Excel` as well as in `Google Sheets`. 1 = 1 day. 1/24 = 1 hour. 1/24/60 = 1 minute. 1/24/60/60 = 1 second.

Comment: cheers that worked! however if I input a current date (today's) in Deal registration and a past date (like last year) it allows for that... why so?

Comment: @htmluser: This data validation only checks whether date of closure is not more than 180 days after date of registration. That was the question. It does not check whether date of closure is before date of registration. Of couse it could by using formula `=AND(B1<B2;INT(B2)<=(INT(B1)+180))`. But that was not the question.

Answer (score 0):

So, basic, but does what is asked:
[image]

Comment: @player0 excel on Mojave (macbook pro 13")